# Possible to use ResponseStatusException and ControllerAdvice together?

Tags: java, spring, error-handling

Before the `ResponseStatusException` was introduced I always used an `@ControllerAdvice` to map exceptions(validation exceptions, custom exceptions,...) to error responses in Java Spring projects.

Now with the `ResponseStatusException` I don't have to map every exception to a response and in general I don't have to create a customException for everything, I can use `ResponseStatusException` directly. I don't want to discuss if it would be better to have custom exceptions instead of `ResponseStatusException`, this is a different topic.

But when I'm handling expected errors with `ResponseStatusException` I still need an `@ControllerAdvice` for handling validation exceptions (`ConstraintViolationException`, `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, ...) and every unexpected error like this.

```java
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> lastDefender(Exception ex)
{
    logger.error("Unhandled error occurred", ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

But the this `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` will fetch the `ResponseStatusException` too (surprise)

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can prevent the `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` from catching ResponseStatusException by specifying it explicitly in a separate method. Here's an example:

```java
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResponseStatusException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleResponseStatusException(ResponseStatusException ex) {
        // Handle ResponseStatusException
        // You can access the HttpStatus from ex.getStatus()
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), ex.getStatus());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleUnexpectedException(Exception ex) {
        // Handle other unexpected exceptions
        // Log the error or perform any other necessary actions
        return new ResponseEntity<>("An unexpected error occurred", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

This way, when a `ResponseStatusException` is thrown, it will be caught by the `handleResponseStatusException` method, and other unexpected exceptions will be caught by the `handleUnexpectedException` method.

Comment: Thanks, I expected something like this. Feels a little bit doubling the work but is logical that something like this is needed